# Sending a domain as parameter to laravel route gives error

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

In my Laravel application I want to give a domain as a option in routing. Note that I don't want this route on a specific domain, but so the route may go like this:
**www.domain.tld/domain/otherdomain.tld/**

Whenever I try this, I get sent to a custom error page, not created by the exceptions you would usually get, but instead I get this: (see picture)
[Error page given if visiting the url as provided as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqXaD.png)

Is it possible to get this up and running without a too big of a tweak?

I use the default .htaccess file provided by laravel.

**Edit 1: Added route definition**

```
Route::get('/domain/{site}', function(){
    echo "Hello world";
});
```

**Edit 2: Virtual host config**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName localhost  
    ServerAlias localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/www
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Can also display the directory config for the document root:

```
<Directory /home/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: What does your route definition look like?

Comment: Edited my main post with the definition, @Bogdan. Have also added a simple custom regex ([a-z.]+) to just see if that could solve it. But with no luck.

Comment: I've just tested this  and it works just fine. Do any other route definitions work, or is ti just this one? Have you checked if your server's URL rewrite module is enabled?

Comment: Just created a completely fresh installation by running `laravel new NAME` in terminal. Added the route and still the same error. Given the fact that the error page i get is not the same page as with thrown exceptions, i do believe it might be a other package included by laravel dependencies or some apache settings which does this. However, i have never seen this error template on other projects on my localhost, so my thoughts wanders towards a other package dependency. And yes, rewrite module is enabled. @Bogdan

Comment: Could you post your Apache virtual host config please?

Comment: It doesn't contain nothing out of the ordinary, but I'll add it to the post, @Bogdan

Comment: So if this is a local develpment enviroment, could you try running `php artisan serve` and see if the routes work with the embedded PHP server (at least to determine if the issue is with your Apache installation).

Comment: Alright, it did work with `php artisan serve`.  For further info I have apache 2.4.7 and php 5.5.9 and is running on ubuntu 14.04, @Bogdan